# encrypt=strict key did not work with System.Data.SqlClient to established TLS 1.3 connection

Tags: c#, sql-server, tls1.3, system.data.sqlclient

I want to establish TLS1.3 Protocol communication between `System.Data.SqlClient` and SQL Server 2022.

As per Microsoft [TDS8](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/networking/tds-8?view=sql-server-ver16#strict-connection-encryption), we need to add Encrypt=strict key in the connection string to established TLS 1.3 connection. But when I added this key below error thrown

> Invalid value for key 'encrypt'

When I keep `encrypt=true` then a TLS 1.2 connection is established. (proper certificate I am using).

Looks like encrypt takes only true/false values only. No strict/optional/mandatory even though MS suggested it.

Sample code:

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace SQLClient
{
    internal class Program
    {
        //sql conn string
        static string sConnStringRemoteSql2k22 = "Encrypt=Strict;Password=Password@123;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Initial Catalog=Testdb;Data Source=sql2k22.test.com;Application Name=test";
        
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(sConnStringRemoteSql2k22);

            try
            {
                string query = "Select * from Players";
                conn.Open();

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);

                using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(dr["Name"].ToString() + " " + dr["dept"].ToString());
                    }
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                conn.Close();
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

**Environment:**

- Microsoft SQL Server 2022 (RTM-CU10) (KB5031778) - 16.0.4095.4 (X64)   Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2022 Standard 10.0  (Build 20348: ) (Hypervisor)
- .NET Framework 4.8.1
- System.Data version 4.0.0.0
- OS: Windows Server 2022

Why does `encrypt=strict` not work with `SqlClient`? Or is there any key I need to add to an established TLS 1.3 connection?

Comment: The `System.Data.SqlClient` assembly is considered to be a legacy client stack that receives no new feature development. Does it work if you use the `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` assembly instead? Specifically, TLS 1.3 support was added to `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` in [version 5.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/ado-net/introduction-microsoft-data-sqlclient-namespace#api-reference).

Comment: The linked docs don't say that you need `Encrypt=strict` anyway. I suspect that if you use Microsoft.Data.SqlClient you'll get TLS 1.3 without having to set anything. In Microsoft.Data.SqlClient connections are encrypted by default

Comment: @AlwaysLearning looks like System.data.SqlClient doesn not support TLS 1.3. (even with latest version 4.8.5) ..using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient able to established TLS 1.3 connection

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos if we did not add Encrypt=strict then TLS 1.2 is established but not TLS 1.3 so for TLS 1.3 we need give strict value manually.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning you should add it as an answer